# Learning arithmetic series

Tags: reference-request, machine-learning, lg.learning

Let us say that an arithmetic series is a series of the form $s_t = \{0, t, 2t, \ldots\}$. For example, $s_3 = \{0, 3, 6, \ldots\}$. Now consider the concept class composed of all arithmetic series of that form, i.e. $S = \{s_0, s_1, s_2, \ldots\}$.

Is there a learning algorithm under the mistake bound model for learning this concept class $S$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An arithmetic series is defined by the 1st term $t_1$ and the difference between terms $d$. If you stipulate that $\max(|t_1|,d)\le M$ then you have a finite hypothesis space and hence a finite mistake bound (e.g., via the halving algorithm). Otherwise, one can make $|t_1|$ arbitrarily large so as to thwart any proposed mistake bound.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! A further question: does there happen to exist a PAC learning algorithm for the concept class of arithmetic series? For simplicity, we can assume that for each concept in the class, the first term $t_1 = 0$ and that the difference between terms $d = 0, 1, 2, \ldots$ across the concepts.

Comment: That should be a new question. Feel free to accept my answer so that this question can be closed.

Comment: I have asked a new question here: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/53543/learning-positive-half-lines-in-mathbbn

Comment: I don't think that question is quite the same as the arithmetic series one but I answered it.